# k8s API Access through python inside the pod

Tags: python, kubernetes, microservices

I have a requirement to get the resource details inside the pod and do some operations depend upon the result. I'm using k8s client python inside the pod. After the role/rolebinding i'm getting forbidden.

i have created Serviceaccount/role/rolebinding as like below.

Can any one help me in this issue.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
name: myaccount
namespace: dev
          
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
namespace: dev
name: pods-reader-role
rules:
-apiGroups: ["*"]
resources: ["*"]
verbs: ["*"]

kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
name: pod-controller
namespace: dev
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
name: myaccount
apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
kind: Role
name: pods-reader-role
apiGroup: ""


Listing pods with their IPs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/scripts/bin/PodCont.py", line 792, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/scripts/bin/PodCont.py", line 596, in main
    ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py", line 16864, in list_pod_for_all_namespaces
    return self.list_pod_for_all_namespaces_with_http_info(**kwargs)  # noqa: E501
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py", line 16981, in list_pod_for_all_namespaces_with_http_info
    collection_formats=collection_formats)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 353, in call_api
    _preload_content, _request_timeout, _host)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 184, in __call_api
    _request_timeout=_request_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 377, in request
    headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 243, in GET
    query_params=query_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 233, in request
    raise ApiException(http_resp=r)
kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (403)
Reason: Forbidden
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Date': 'Mon, 05 Apr 2021 09:47:13 GMT', 'Content-Length': '285'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"pods is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:dev:deploy-svc-account\" cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"kind":"pods"},"code":403}
```

Comment: Could you check the indentation in your listings? It does not look right. Maybe that's the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Answering the question, I think there are some things that should be considered:

- Indentation
- Service account running the `Pod`
- Python code and access scopes

As there is no [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we can at most assume on how exactly you've configured your setup.

---

#### Indentation

The `YAML` manifest that you've included will is not indented correctly. The correct manifest should look like below:

- `full.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: myaccount
  namespace: dev
---          
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: pods-reader-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: pod-controller
  namespace: dev
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: myaccount
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: pods-reader-role
  apiGroup: ""
```

> A side note!
>
> Consider creating more restrictive `Role` for your use case as it's allowing to do everything in the `dev` namespace.

---

#### Service account running the `Pod`

The potential issue here is that you've created a `serviceAccount` with a name: `myaccount`
and the `Pod` is trying to authenticate using the `deploy-svc-account`. (`User \"system:serviceaccount:dev:deploy-svc-account\" cannot list resource`)

Please ensure that the correct `serviceAccount` is used to run a `Pod`.

Example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: sdk
  namespace: dev
spec:
  serviceAccountName: myaccount # <-- IMPORTANT
  containers:
  - image: google/cloud-sdk
    command:
      - sleep
      - "infinity"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: sdk
  restartPolicy: Always
```

---

#### Python code and access scopes

Assuming that you've used the code from the documentation page of Kubernetes Python API library (`"Listing pods with their IPs:"`):

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes client: Python](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/)*

There are 2 topics to consider here:

- Access scopes
- Querying the resources

Citing the official documentation:

> **A Role always sets permissions within a particular namespace**; when you create a Role, you have to specify the namespace it belongs in.
>
> *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Reference: RBAC: Role and ClusterRole](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole)*

The permissions that you've assigned by a `Role` and a `RoleBinding` are for `dev` namespace only. If you would like to have full cluster scope you would need to create a `ClusterRole` and a `ClusterRoleBinding`.

I encourage you to check the documentation included in the citation as it has some examples to follow and there are many explanations on that matter.

Also, a word about the Python code:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config

# Configs can be set in Configuration class directly or using helper utility
config.load_incluster_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
for i in ret.items:
    print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
```

Focusing on:

```py
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
```

This code will query for `Pods` from all namespaces, that's why you've also receiving the error `cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope"`.

To list the `Pods` from a specific namespace you can use:

```py
ret = v1.list_namespaced_pod(namespace="dev", watch=False)
```

And by that you should be able to get:

- `python3 program.py`:

```sh
Listing pods with their IPs:
10.32.0.15  dev sdk
```

Comment: thanks Dawid Kruk i missed the servicename in deployment.yaml that fixed my issue.